# Can I process Django fixture data before it is written to the database?

Tags: django, django-fixtures

Let us say you have a simple model with a mandatory foreign key:

```
class Pupil(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)
```

I want to load Pupil instances from a fixture file but add a default teacher in my code such that the teacher must not be entered in the fixture file:

```
- model: models.Pupil
  pk: 1
  fields: { name: "Max" }
```

I tried to assign the teacher in **init** like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.teacher = Teacher()
```

and similar things also in save but without success.

Comment: you mean ``class Pupil(models.Model):`` instead of ``class Pupil:`` right?

Comment: do it in separate *.py file (you can add it's call to fabfile) or in django shell, because data fixtures semantically cannot have logic manipulation

Comment: @doniyor: Right, fixed, thanks.

Comment: you need to look up how to use `super` https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super maybe also how instance attributes work (hint: `self.teacher`)

Comment: you want all pupils to have the same teacher, or every pupil to have a different teacher?

Comment: @Anentropic: Each one has its own teacher. Of course pupil/teacher is not the real problem domain ;)

Comment: re `self.teacher` it was the `__init__` method that was wrong not the class definition. you need to read some basic information about Python language and think through carefully what you are doing

Comment: @Anentropi: Look here https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super